# Throughput's change is not logical when mobile UEs are increasing their distance

Tags: omnet++, throughput

I'm trying to measure throughput when the distance between two mobile UE is changing. I'm using Omnet++. and measuring throughput in the mac layer.

It's supposed to be that when the distance increases throughput should decrease (well-known inverse relationship)

But in my simulation it doesn't happen. Does anyone have any idea about it in omnet++?
I also attached the chart of throughput during the time
enter image description here[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxxBa.png)
Thanks

Comment: It is hard to help you without providing any information about your setup, frameworks, network,...

Answer (score 0):

@thardes2 Ok, I'm using Omnet++. In my scenario, there is 1 base station and 2 UE without any mobility during the simulation. I run the simulation 20 times (10,20,30 ,... 200m) and try to measure the throughput which is calculated in the MAC layer in the LteHarqBufferRx.cc (in a way total received bytes / simulation time)

double tputSample = (double)totalRcvdBytes_ / (NOW - getSimulation()->getWarmupPeriod());

macOwner_->emit(macThroughput_, tputSample);

I used *SinglePair-UDP-Infra* scenario in *D2D* sample in *Simulte* and verything is working well, but my issue is: Why throughput doesn't reduce when distance increases? Even in some long distance throughput increases!!!  Am I calculating throughput in a wrong place?

Thank you for your help